# imagecreatefromjpeg() function not geting file

Tags: php

imagecreatefromjpeg() function says file not exists, but when I check using file_exists() function, it says exists.

PHP code is like,

```
    $path = "/home/content/html/uploads/test.jpg";

    if(file_exists($path)) {
        echo "Exists!";
    } else {
        echo "File Not Exists!";
    }    

    $resize = new Resize($path, $img['name']);
    $resize->resizeImage($size[0], $size[1]);
    $resize->preview();
```

And I got the output like,

```
Exists!
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(/home/content/html/uploads/test.jpg) [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/html/includes/resize.php on line 20
```

Directory structure,

- /html

  - /uploads

    - test.jpg
  - index.php

Comment: What is your directory structure? Is `html/` your web root?

Comment: @BenM, yes html/ is my webroot.

Comment: Check file permissions

Comment: Weird. Can you do a `clearstatcache()` before the file_exists just to make sure it's not using old data?

Comment: Then simply specify `uploads/test.jpg`. No need for the hidden virtual directory references.

Comment: @BenM but what if he's including the code from somewhere else? It can't be the source of the problem either way, looking at the `file_exists` result

Comment: @Pekka웃 I ran into a similar problem in the past. `file_exists()` reported true, but the image couldn't be opened using `imagecreatefromjpeg()`. Turned out to be an odd setting in Apache, and removing references outside of the web root worked. Worth a shot.

Comment: @MarkBaker, file permission are like, for web user it's read and execute, and for owner it's read, write and execute.

Comment: I tested the same code in localhost using wamp, and it works. But not working in server.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? As I said I had a similar problem and it turned out to be an odd setting in Apache...

Comment: @BenM Sorry for delay. I use "uploads/test.jpg" but it's not working

Comment: Since it works on WAMP and not on your server, I'd probably look at the `phpinfo()` for both and see what's different.

Comment: @BenM OK, I will compare both phpinfo() files and will update then. Thanks for such great response.

Comment: @BenM, In phpinfo(), Virtual Directory Support is set to disabled. Other than that both looks similar to me.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got the solution. But first I want to thanks all who help me.

It's very weird problem. In server, imagecreatefromjpeg() will only work if there is filepath without "space".

If I convert spaces into %20 using rawurlencode(), then problem persist, so what I have to do is, convert spaces into something else using str_replace() function,  during file upload.

```
str_replace(" ", "_", $filename);
```

On localhost I am using "test.jpg" file, but on server there are many diffrent files with spaces in there name, so I use "test.jpg" in my qustion. (Sorry for that)